# fiber of holomorphic bundle as pull back sheaf

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, holomorphic-bundles

Let $f:(X,\mathcal{R}_X)\to (Y,\mathcal{R}_Y)$ be the map between two topological space,with the sheaf of ring.

Given a sheaf of $\mathcal{R}_Y-$module  $\mathcal{N}$,we can define the inverse image as usual by $f^{-1}(\mathcal{N})$ which is a $f^{-1}(\mathcal{R}_Y)-$module, define the pull back be the sheaf

$$f^*\mathcal{N} = \mathcal{R}_ X \otimes _{f^{-1}\mathcal{R}_ Y} f^{-1}\mathcal{N}
$$
Here is an example:
Given the inclusion $i:\{x\}\to X$ ,with $X$ the complex manifold with structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$.prove the pull-back sheaf can be computed as :$$i^*\mathcal{N} = \mathcal{N}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}\mathcal{O}_{\{x\}}$$

Moreover if taking $\mathcal{N}$ the sheaf of the sections over holomorphic bundle of $X$,then it's isomorphic to the firber of the bundle.

Comment: For the first question I can write out the presheaf associated to the tensor product by just noticing that the inverse image of $\mathcal{N}$ under the one point inclusion is the stalk $\mathcal{N}_x$.But I have not idea how to take sheafification.